# convert zipcode to longitude and latitude

Tags: api, google-maps, csv, latitude-longitude, zipcode

I want to convert zipcode to longitude and latitude and write to a csv file. I use `storelocator` by google and I need to place marker only with zipcode...

```
for (var i = 1, row; row = rows[i]; i++) {
    row = this.toObject_(headings, this.parseRow_(row));
    var features = new storeLocator.FeatureSet;
    features.add(this.FEATURES_.getById('Wheelchair-' + row.Wheelchair));
    features.add(this.FEATURES_.getById('Audio-' + row.Audio));

    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(row.Ycoord, row.Xcoord);


    var shop = this.join_([row.Shp_num_an, row.Shp_centre], ', ');
    var locality = this.join_([row.Locality, row.Postcode], ', ');

    var store = new storeLocator.Store(row.uuid, position, features, {
        title: row.titre,
        address: this.join_([shop, row.Street_add, locality], '<br>'),
        hours: row.Hrs_of_bus
    });
    stores.push(store);
}
```

Comment: That is called [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)

Comment: Geocoding (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) is the way to do it. But be warned - it is not 100% accurate. It gives you it's best result for a given address. But if it doesn't know the address, it will return a result that you might not expect. It's definitely worth looking into restricting by country (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#ComponentRestrictions)

Comment: Fix some punctuation.